# Reading in key-values from a text file in Perl, skipping comments

Tags: perl, hashmap, text-processing

I'm looking to read in a folder full of text files and store values in hash tables. A sample text file looks like this:

**sample.txt**

```
title: Sample Soft
version: 1
category: utility
os_support: Linux
date_added: 01/01/1998
# Lines beginning '#' are skipped
This is a new line.
This is <b>bold</b> to test HTML.
```

I wrote a Perl subroutine that takes the filename as a parameter. My Perl subroutine looks as follows:

```
sub read_entry {
    my $key = $_[0];
    open (ENTRY, "$entrydir/$key") or die "Couldn't open $entrydir/$key";
    $key =~ s/\.txt//;

    while (<ENTRY>) {
        if (my @entrykv = split /:\s*/) {
            # store key-value pair here, key value is $key
            print @entrykv;
        } elsif (! /^#/) {
            say "NOT COMMENT";
            $desc{$key} += $_;
        }
    }

    close ENTRY; 
}
```

What I have it doing is iterate through each line in the text file. When it matches a *descriptor* which is the name terminated by a colon (e.g. `title:`) then it will store the corresponding *value* on the right hand side of the line (e.g. `Sample Soft`) into a hashmap.

I have hashmaps named for these descriptors which are read from the text files. The first line of the text file should be read into a hashmap named "title". The text file name with the `.txt` chopped off is the key value for these hashmaps, that's the variable `$key` in my code. Eg, if we read in "sample.txt" then this value would be "sample". So there will be a hashmap of titles, versions, categories, &c, with the values indexed by the $key variable extracted from the text file names.

In other words, this is what the subroutine should read from the file:

```
$key = "sample";
$title{$key} = "Sample Soft";
$version{$key} = "1";
$category{$key} = "utility";
$os_support{$key} = "Linux";
$date_added{$key} = "01/01/1998";
$desc{$key} = "This is a new line.\nThis is <b>bold</b> to test HTML.";
```

The input should also disregard any comments (lines beginning #) and the rest of the text file, which doesn't match the descriptor-value format, will be stored in a `$desc{$key}` hashmap.

The split function works, for the meantime I have it simply printing what it just split. However, the values aren't yet stored in the hashmaps. Also, the if conditional doesn't work. I still see comments and the description printed.

I'd greatly appreciate any help fixing the conditional and finishing the reading of the key-values.

Comment: Using a hash of hashes would be easier, either `$software{title}{$key}`, or maybe even `$software{$key}{title} = 'Sample Soft'` - it depends on what you want to do with the data later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some solutions, but I thought it would be interesting to explain some of the problems with your existing code.

You say:

> Also, the if conditional doesn't work. I still see comments and the description printed.

Let's start by looking at that.

Your conditional is this:

```
if (my @entrykv = split /:\s*/) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

You're hoping for that to distinguish between your key/value lines and the lines that contain the description (and, therefore, don't contain a ":"). I think you misunderstand what `split()` does. In the case where the line contains a ":", `split()` returns a list with two items. That list gets put into the array, `@entrykv`, and the `if` statement evaluates that array in a scalar context which gives the value 2 (as there are two elements in the array). 2 is a true value, so we get into the "true" part of the `if`/`else` statement.

In the case where we don't have a ":" in the line, `split()` will return a list with a single element (containing the whole line). That, again, gets put into `@entrykv` and the `if` statement evaluates that in scalar context. That gives the value 1 and 1 is still a true value and we still end up in the "true" part pf the `if`/`else` statement.

So you need to do something different here. The best approach is probably to check for the existence of a ":" in the line. Something like this:

```
if (/:/) {
  my @entrykv = split /:\s*/; #/ stupid SO highlighter
  print "@entrykv\n";
} elsif (! /^#/) {
  print "Not a comment\n";
  $desc{$key} .= $_;
}
```

Oh, and that's a second point. You used `+=` to add to the end of the description. That's not right. Perl uses `.` as the concatenation operator - so you need `.=` here.

And there's one other problem here that goes right to the heart of the design. You have separate hashes for each of the attributes. That's a really bad idea. IF you have a data item with many attributes, you should try to keep all of those attributes together in a single variable. And a hash is a perfect way to store all of those attributes together.

Your `read_entry()` subroutine reads a single file. And I think that each file just contains a single "key" (e.g. "sample"). So I think it makes sense for that subroutine to return a reference to a hash which contains all of the data from that file. It might look like this:

```
sub read_entry {
  my ($filename) = @_;

  my $key = $filename;
  $key =~ s/\.txt$//; #/ stupid SO highlighter

  # use a) lexical filehandle and b) three-arg version of open()
  open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!\n";

  my %data;
  while (<$fh>) {
    # Skip comments
    next if /^#/;

    if (/:/) {
      chomp;
      my ($key, $val) = split /:\s*/; #/ stupid SO highlighter
      $data{$key} = $val;
    } else {
      $data{desc} .= $_;
    }
  }

  return \%data;
}
```

Comment: Dave, thanks very much for taking the time to write this. I'm sorry that I didn't get back sooner to give thanks, it's been a wild month that incidently began shortly after I started writing this script. Such is the power of Perl, transcending our supposedly clear divisions of the physical and digital worlds.
I think I've a bit more to learn in my journey, but I really love the language and find lucid, helpful posts like this encouraging. Best wishes.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would approach it.

Build a regex to extract the known entries from the file.

Skipping the comment is the first thing to do. You don't want to investigate a line starting with an octothorpe.

Use a hash of hashes to store the details. You don't have to branch depending on what detail you're extracting.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $entrydir = '.';
my @recognised = qw( title version category os_support date_added );
my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, @recognised;
$regex = qr/^($regex):/;  #/ stupid SO highlighter

sub read_entry {
    my ($key) = @_;

    open my $in, '<', "$entrydir/$key" or die $!;
    $key =~ s/\.txt$//;  #/ stupid SO highlighter

    my %details;
    while (<$in>) {
        next if /^#/;

        if (/$regex(.*)/) {
            $details{$1} = $2;
        } else {
            $details{desc} .= $_;
        }
    }
    return $key, \%details
}

my %software;
for my $file (@ARGV) {
    my ($key, $details) = read_entry($file);
    $software{$key} = $details;
}
use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%software;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. You can store the data values using hash of hashes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use File::Basename;

no warnings 'uninitialized';

my $path  = '/home/location/mention/sample.txt'; #either pass as an argument $ARGV[0]
my $fname = basename($path);

my $f;
if ($fname =~ /(\w+).txt/) { $f = $1; }

open my $fh, '<', $path or die "Cannot open file: $path\n";

my %hash = ();
my ($title, $ver, $category, $os, $date, $description);

while (<$fh>){
    chomp;

    next if($_ =~ /^#/);

    if( $_ =~ /:/){
        if( $_ =~ /title: (.*)/)      { $hash{$f}{'TITLE'}    = $1; }
        if( $_ =~ /version: (\d+)/)   { $hash{$f}{'VERSION'}  = $1; }
        if( $_ =~ /category: (\w+)/)  { $hash{$f}{'CATEGORY'} = $1; }
        if( $_ =~ /os_support: (\w+)/){ $hash{$f}{'OS'}       = $1; }
        if( $_ =~ /date_added: (.*)/) { $hash{$f}{'DATE'}     = $1; }
    } else {
        $description = $_;
        $hash{$f}{'DESC'} = $hash{$f}{'DESC'}.$description;
    }
}
print Dumper(\%hash);

close $fh;
```

In the `%hash` Dumper, you can see the structure of content how its been stored.

PS: To read data from each line `regex` can be improved.